# How to use iOS's WKWebView's callAsyncJavaScript method?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios14

I'm encountering a crash when using [the `callAsyncJavaScript(...)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript):

> Fatal error: Bug in WebKit: Received neither result or failure.: file WebKit/WebKitSwiftOverlay.swift, line 66

My code:

```swift
webView.callAsyncJavaScript(
    "console.log('foo');",
    arguments: [:],
    in: nil,
    in: .defaultClient // I also tried `.page`.
) { print($0) }
```

The code runs, and I see the `console.log` print out `foo`. But it crashes before the `print` runs. I've been searching for clues, but haven't been able to find anything. It says "Bug in WebKit". If that's the case, is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

After more searching, I found an example from https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc20/10188/

[image]